# Matrix diagonalizable over $\Bbb C$ but not invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Is there a matrix that is diagonalizable over $\Bbb C$ but not invertible?

I can only think of a matrix that is diagonalizable over $\Bbb R$ but not invertible.

Comment: One of the eigenvalues can be zero.

Comment: Since $\mathbb{R}$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ any matrix which is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{R}$ is diagonizable over $\mathbb{C}$. Secondly, surely the $n\times n$ zero matrix is diagonizable?

Comment: Your example over R, whatever it is, is also an example over C. Also: the zero matrix.

Answer (score 3):

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $\Bbb R\subset \Bbb C$, all examples you have in hand for $\Bbb R$ works for $\Bbb C$ as well. Easiest example will be zero matrix.

Another useful hint will be that a matrix is invertible $\iff$ its eigenvalues are nonzero and think about a matrix which satisfies the polynomial $x(x^2+1)=0$

Another way to generate many examples as you wish is:

Find a $2\times2$ matrix $A$ with complex conjugate roots. Then matrix $B_{3\times3}=\left[\begin{matrix} 0 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && A_{2\times2} \\ 0 \end{matrix} \right]$ will be diagonalizable (since it has distinct eigenvalues), and is not invertible since one of the eigenvalues are zero.